# Awk doesn't work when inside double quotes

Tags: linux, shell, awk

This command doesn't work:

```
ssh $HOST "ls -l | awk '{print $1}'"`
```

Above ignores the command `awk`.  I think it might be because of the double quotes?

Also, how would I add another set of double quotes inside the awk?

ie:

```
ssh $HOST "awk '{print $1 "*"}' /some_file"
```

I tried escaping the quotes, I even tried this:

```
ssh $HOST "awk '{print $1 "\""*"\""}' /some_file"
```

without success.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Variable interpolation is performed within double quotes, so here's what I think might be happening: when you type in `ssh $HOST "ls -l | awk '{print $1}'"`, your shell (the one on your local computer, where you are running the SSH client) sees `$1` within the double quotes and replaces it with the value of the variable `$1`, which will be blank. It isn't able to detect that the `$1` is nested within single quotes within the double quotes. So what winds up getting sent to the remote server is

```
ls -l | awk '{print }'
```

which is basically equivalent to

```
ls -l | cat
```

i.e. it just prints out the output of `ls -l`.

Solution: escape the `$` with a backslash,

```
ssh $HOST "ls -l | awk '{print \$1}'"
```

Comment: Haha, that was so simple! I just looked right through it!

This did exactly what I wanted.
ssh $HOST "ls -l | awk '{print \$1 \"*\"}'"


Thanks a bunch!